# How does this transformation work?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, machine-learning, neural-networks

$$-\frac{N}{2}\ln|\Sigma|-\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^N (t_n-y_n)^T\Sigma^{-1}(t_n-y_n).$$

By rewriting the second term, we get

$$-\frac{N}{2}\ln|\Sigma|-\frac12 \operatorname{Tr}\left[\Sigma^{-1}\sum_{n=1}^N (t_n-y_n) (t_n-y_n)^T\right]$$

How does this transformation work?

Also, one more thing. What is $\Sigma$ if I was to set the derivative wrt to $\Sigma^{-1}$ for the above to 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $(t_n-y_n)^T\Sigma^{-1}(t_n-y_n)$ is a scalar, hence it is equal to its trace.

\begin{align}
(t_n-y_n)^T\Sigma^{-1}(t_n-y_n) &= \operatorname{Tr}\left( (t_n-y_n)^T\Sigma^{-1}(t_n-y_n)\right) \\
&=\operatorname{Tr}\left( \Sigma^{-1}(t_n-y_n)(t_n-y_n)^T\right) \\
\end{align}

since trace of $AB$ is equal to trace of $BA$.

Also, notice that the trace of sum is equal to the sum of trace.

Comment: Also, one more thing. What is Σ if I was to set the derivative wrt to Σ−1for the above to 0.

Comment: [matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) reference, try to differentiate it.

Comment: I got to $\Sigma^{-1} = (-1/N)(\sum_{n=1}^N (t_n-y_n) (t_n-y_n)^T)$ but idk how to make it just $\Sigma$

Comment: Do you mean you want to set them to be equal and you want to figure out how? take inverse on both sides?  your solution is a bit counter intuitive to me.

Comment: Can you show me how you do it? I don;t think I can work this one out myself

Comment: I can't solve the question you added too. You might want to open a new question including your working in your post. Try to stick to one question per post. Your current answer doesn't makes sense. as it is negative definite. I would guess an answer to be something like a multiple to your right hand side without the negative sign.